# Automatic deployement with Jenkins/jetty

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I would like to setup a continuous integration environment whereby after committing the source code, it triggers a build process that checks out the code, runs tests, constructs a war file and deploys the same to jetty server such that the users/testers can access the application on the browser.

Is this possible ?

Am using maven and jetty (I am not willing to change this. I use jetty both for development and in production). For CI, I am exploring Jenkins but am open to other opensource solutions.

If possible, how do I setup the environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a maven plugin named cargo. It has everything that I needed. I added it into my pom so that I could deploy and undeploy using mvn cargo:deploy/mvn cargo:undeploy. I created a new jenkins job and added undeploy, package deploy maven goals as build steps. Everything is working perfectly.

Comment: can you publish your example? did you create a separate module for deployment? do you execute "mcn cargo:deploy" on that module level or on the root level? etc

Comment: The project had a single web module. Even with multiple modules...i just need to ensure that the web module can compile on its own and then use cargo on the web module only.

Answer (score 3):

it's definitely possible. In a previous project, the build server (teamcity) copied the war to a shared nfs location between the build server and the application server and run a little shell script that connected to the application server and restarted jetty.

We used ant inside maven to manage the deployment, I remember we used the copy and [sshexec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) tasks.

I'm sure that there are many other solutions, but that one worked for us.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help. Josh.

Comment: I decided to use simple "scp" command to copy WAR to the server. cargo plugin didn't work, was too complicated and didn't give any value.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed a lot of posts like this but I want something that is maven independent. Look here, this is selfcontained runner in on hudson/jenkins. You only need 'war', even manual jetty installation is not needed. [Deploy war on jetty in Jenkins or Hudson job](http://www.77dev.com/2013/05/deploy-war-on-jetty-in-jenkins-or.html)